# Mass deployment of APK to android phones

Tags: android, python

I apologize in advance if this is not in the right section, I've searched extensively for an answer to this and I'm not sure if I don't have the terminology correct or what but I can't seem to find anything on it.

My job involves deploying many android devices, generally 100+, to clients with their chosen set of software already loaded onto the device.

---

I wrote a python script that basically gets all the devices plugged in via usb, loops through and installs apks onto the phones one at a time using ADB.

This was working just fine until we started using Samsung devices that pop up a "allow google to verify apps" message once you try to communicate with them via ADB, which ends up cancelling the install.

---

To try and combat this, I created an update.zip with the desired apks, signed it, and installed it.  The zip works on my rooted nexus 5, but the Samsungs wont accept it, im assuming because they are not rooted.

So my question is this, is there a better way to deploy multiple apps to large quantity of devices simultaneously?  I was hoping to edit my python script to accommodate but im not sure if thats possible anymore.  I can post it's source here if needed.

Any help is appreciated, installing 10+ apps on 100+ devices takes a lot of time, automating it would be a huge help.